# how can I apply 2 conditions in join in HQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm, hql

How can I apply 2 conditions in join in HQL? I want to write HQL for below query:

Pervious HQL:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("from Hardwarekomponente h");
        sb.append(" left join fetch h.hwCategory4 c4");
        sb.append(" left join fetch c4.hwCategory3 c3");
        sb.append(" where h.konto.sisnetConfigSwitch = 1");
        sb.append(" and h.technischeNr is not null");
        sb.append(" and upper(c3.hwCategory3) like :cat3");
```

Previous SQL:

```
SELECT  *
FROM     HARDWAREKOMPONENTE h 
         INNER JOIN V_MD_HARDWARE_CAT4 c4 ON h.Hw_Kategorie4_Id=c4.Hardware_Cat4_Id 
         INNER JOIN V_MD_HARDWARE_CAT3 c3 ON c4.Hardware_Cat3_Id=c3.Hardware_Cat3_Id 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN V_MD_ACCOUNT k ON h.Konto_Id=k.Account_Id  
WHERE    (h.Technische_Nr is not null) and (upper(c3.Hardware_Cat3) like '%SWITCH%') and k.Sisnet_Config_Switch = 1;
```

But now due to some changes, I want to move 2 conditions along with join to get some output which the previous query was not giving me:

New HQL(which I am trying for, but its failing for with operator):

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("from Hardwarekomponente h ");
        sb.append(" left join fetch h.hwCategory4 c4 with (upper(c3.hwCategory3) like :cat3) ");
        sb.append(" left join fetch c4.hwCategory3 c3 with (h.konto.sisnetConfigSwitch = 1)  ");
        // sb.append(" where h.konto.kontoId = :account");
        sb.append(" where ");
        sb.append("  h.technischeNr is not null ");
```

New SQL:

```
SELECT  *
FROM     HARDWAREKOMPONENTE h 
         INNER JOIN V_MD_HARDWARE_CAT4 c4 ON h.Hw_Kategorie4_Id=c4.Hardware_Cat4_Id 
         INNER JOIN V_MD_HARDWARE_CAT3 c3 ON c4.Hardware_Cat3_Id=c3.Hardware_Cat3_Id AND (upper(c3.Hardware_Cat3) like '%SWITCH%')
         LEFT OUTER JOIN V_MD_ACCOUNT k ON h.Konto_Id=k.Account_Id AND k.Sisnet_Config_Switch = 1
WHERE    (h.Technische_Nr is not null);
```

So, my question was how can I add or tell Hibernate to add conditions along with join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first `with` statement you are referring to an alias which is not yet defined (`c3`).

I would structure the query as follows:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  sb.append("from Hardwarekomponente h ");
  sb.append(" left join h.konto k with (k.sisnetConfigSwitch = 1)");  
  sb.append(" left join h.hwCategory4 c4");
  sb.append(" left join c4.hwCategory3 c3 with (upper(c3.hwCategory3) like :cat3) ");
  sb.append(" where ");
  sb.append("  h.technischeNr is not null ");
```

Comment: I am still getting 

`•An unexpected error occured. Details: with-clause not allowed on fetched associations; use filters `

Comment: can you remove the fetch clauses and lazy-load the dependencies later in the transactional method?

Comment: Can I know the reason, why with fetch it was not working?

Comment: Hql does not support with statement along with eager fetching. If lazy loading cannot be applied then you are left with filters like the error says. But you dont have that problem

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162398/discussion-between-indu-kaur-and-maciej-kowalski).

Comment: Can we have sub-query in hql?

I have a condition in where clause. like

`where h.konto is null or h.konto in (select h.konto from Konto k where k.del_quelle is null)`

Comment: when I use this, I am getting unexpected token '('
can u suggest me proper syntax please.

Comment: have you closed all your brackets?

Comment: Yes. Its my mistake. Sorry

Comment: Can u let me know how we can eliminate the property to appear in select sql
Because in hibernate when we create properties in hbm and when we use that class, all its properties appear in select .

for eg, my konto.hbm has kontoName, kontoId, kontoDate properties and I am using it in my query for where clause but I don't want its properties to be part of select but then too its appearing. 

how can we avoid that?

Comment: Any answers for me?

Comment: you can make it transient.. but remembe that you will not be able to persist that as well

Comment: Ahh...but I have to persist it in other functions :(

I am getting class cast exception after modifying the query

Comment: Previous query:

`sb.append("from Hardwarekomponente h");
  sb.append(" left join fetch h.hwCategory4 c4");
  sb.append(" left join fetch c4.hwCategory3 c3");
  // sb.append(" where h.konto.kontoId = :account");
  sb.append(" where h.konto.sisnetConfigSwitch = 1");
  sb.append(" and h.technischeNr is not null");
  sb.append(" and upper(c3.hwCategory3) like :cat3");`

Comment: Modified query:

`StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  sb.append("from Hardwarekomponente h ");
  sb.append(" inner join h.hwCategory4 c4 ");
  sb.append(" inner join c4.hwCategory3 c3 with (upper(c3.hwCategory3) like :cat3 ) ");
  sb.append(" left join h.konto k with (k.sisnetConfigSwitch = 1) ");
  sb.append(" where h.konto in ( ");
  sb.append(" select kn.kontoId from KontoNew kn where kn.delQuelle is null ");
  sb.append(" ) ");
  sb.append(" and h.technischeNr is not null ");`

Comment: can u suggest something?